# Chrome dev tools crash: Cannot read property 'pseudoType' of undefined

Tags: chrome

When using the Chrome (`v71.0.3578.98`) developer tools on Ubuntu 18.04 I get a complete system freeze fairly regularly.

It's the kind of freeze that locks the mouse, and prevents even `Ctrl+Alt+f1`. I can only continue working by using "[the magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)".

I've had a look in `var/log/syslog` and the last thing the system did before doing nothing for a long time involves loading Chrome extensions and includes this:

```
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]: [5705:5721:0227/192015.998704:ERROR:extension_protocols.cc(568)] Allowing load of chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.postload.js.mapfrom unknown origin. Could not find user data for request.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]: [5705:5721:0227/192053.261140:ERROR:extension_protocols.cc(568)] Allowing load of chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.preload.js.mapfrom unknown origin. Could not find user data for request.
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]: [5705:5705:0227/192055.471838:ERROR:CONSOLE(970)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pseudoType' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'pseudoType' of undefined
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at SDK.DOMNode._removeChild (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:4303:28)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at SDK.DOMModel._childNodeRemoved (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:4422:121)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at SDK.DOMDispatcher.childNodeRemoved (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:4465:54)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at Protocol.InspectorBackend._DispatcherPrototype.dispatch (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:3402:26)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at SDK.Target._onMessage (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:3353:31)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at SDK.MainConnection._dispatchMessage (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:3490:41)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at Common.Object.dispatchEventToListeners (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:490:23)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at innerDispatch (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:970:98)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at Host.InspectorFrontendAPIImpl._dispatch (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js:970:1)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]:     at DevToolsAPIImpl._dispatchOnInspectorFrontendAPI (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_compatibility.js:57:36)", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (970)
Feb 27 19:20:57 rob-hp-pavilion org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1549]: [5705:5721:0227/192057.083931:ERROR:extension_protocols.cc(568)] Allowing load of chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/include.postload.js.mapfrom unknown origin. Could not find user data for request.
```

The extension being loaded (according to its ID) is Adblocker Plus.

Is this a known issue?

---

### Update

I've removed Adblock Plus and it still happens. It's nothing to do with the extension loading.

Comment: found this while experiencing the same error message while using python selenium on windows.

specifically  during browser.get  on url as below.



from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(https://www.taste.com.au/recipes/apple-raspberry-crumble-tea-cake-recipe/21x6gub4)



using chromedriver.exe for chrome Version 73

Comment: I've got this error using Electron in dev mode. (Haven't tested in a build.)